# How to configure single folder's settings in vscode workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

[vscode document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uYsX.png)

The document told me that:
The concept of a workspace enables VS Code to:

- Configure settings that only apply to a specific folder or folders but not others.
  but I can not find the config method in the document.

I'm trying to configure settings that only apply to a specific folder but not others.
I've tried the configuration below, but no one validated it, does anybody know how to config that?

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "smart_claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "claim-libaries",
            "settings": {
                "typescript.validate.enable": false,
                "javascript.validate.enable": false
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "health-claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "pet-claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "xhb-claim"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "typescript.validate.enable": true,
        "javascript.validate.enable": true
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "smart_claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "claim-libaries",
            "typescript.validate.enable": false,
            "javascript.validate.enable": false
        },
        {
            "path": "health-claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "pet-claim"
        },
        {
            "path": "xhb-claim"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "typescript.validate.enable": true,
        "javascript.validate.enable": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you "open a workspace" , create a file..put some dummy text into it and try to close the editor. VSCode will then ask if you want to save your workspace, and will automatically generate the workspace config for you

Comment: why post an image of a web page that you could also copy paste the text and post the URL